# Change dns nameserver - Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

When I edit `/etc/resolv.conf`, it is overwritten right away with the old configuration. How do I *really* change the nameserver on Ubuntu Server 9.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

1. Backup your resolv.conf

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.auto
   ```
2. Edit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
   ```
3. If there are any nameservers, write them down for future reference.
4. Replace the reference line, or add:

   ```
   prepend domain-name-servers 1.2.3.4,4.3.2.1;
   ```
5. Save and exit!
6. Restart any Internet clients and services
7. Test your new settings.

This should work in 9.10 just fine.

Comment: You even knew the DNS server I wanted! Thanks, it worked

Comment: that's amazing! that's the same combination i have on my luggage!

Comment: Why did you edit out a working DNS server, for one that doesn't exist?

Comment: Me? Well I'd figure you already had your own in mind :-\